# Query works in sql server 2012 but not in server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I created below query it's works good in sql server 2012 but not working in sql server 2008 or 2008R2. Please help me to resolve this.

```
Select Batchno, BatchId, Transactiontype, LoanAccountNumber, TransactionId
    , StaticDetailId, Name, Comment, BatchTotal
    , case when Amount<0 then Amount*-1 
           Else Amount End as Amount
    , ((BatchTotal) - (SUM(case when Amount<0 then Amount*-1 Else Amount End) 
           OVER(order BY Batchno ROWS BETWEEN 1000 Preceding and current row))) AS BatchBal 
From (SELECT row_number() over (order by BO.BatchID) as [BatchNo]
           , BO.BatchID, sd.TransactionType, tra.LoanAccountNumber, tra.TransactionID
           , tra.StaticDetailID,tra.Name,tra.Comment, BO.BatchTotal,tra.Amount
        FROM BackOfficeBatchTransactionDetails tra
        join BackOfficeBatchDetails BO 
            on BO.BatchID=tra.BatchID and tra.isactive=1 and tra.isdeleted=0 
        join StaticDetails sd on sd.StaticDetailID=tra.StaticDetailID and sd.isactive=1
        where BO.isactive=1 and BO.isdeleted=0 AND BO.BatchId=@BatchID
     ) AS G
```

Comment: The code is pretty unreadable in this format, but I'm putting my money on this being the reason: `ROWS BETWEEN 1000 Preceding and current row`. If I'm not mistaking, that syntax was only recently introduced in SQ Server.

Comment: Yes this syntax is in sql server 2012 that is the reason it's not working in 2008. Please suggests so that it can works in 2008 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the query failing is this bit of the statement:

```
ROWS BETWEEN 1000 Preceding and current row
```

The `ROWS` (and `RANGE` keywords were only introduced in SQL Server 2012:

http://www.pawlowski.cz/2012/06/ms-sql-2012-window-functions-introduction/

Comment: Thanks, but is there any to change this query so that it can works in 2008 also. Please help me for the same.

Comment: @VidyaVikasMishra It will need a significant re-write. This is a new feature of Sql Server 2012, and without you have to re-think how you write the query.